# Ineffective Array Shuffler

Tags: c#, arrays, random, shuffle

I am attempting to shuffle an array, but the way I am doing it only works about every fifth time. I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain why it is not working properly and perhaps propose a tweak.

```
private Button[] scrambleBoard(Button[] buttons)
{
    for (int x = 100 * buttons.Count(); x > 0; x--)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int first = rand.Next(buttons.Count());
        int second = rand.Next(buttons.Count());


        Button temp = buttons[first];
        buttons[first] = buttons[second];
        buttons[second] = temp;
    }

    return buttons;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the following line outside the loop:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

The default seed used by `System.Random` is based on `Environment.TickCount`. In a tight loop, the tick-count may not change between successive iterations, so it may end up using with the same seed over and over. Consequently, the loop will repeatedly swap the *same* two elements until the tick-count changes (it may not do so before the loop completes).  To verify that this is the issue, you can try adding a `Thread.Sleep(100)`  or similar inside the loop; you should then be able to see the shuffle working correctly (albeit very slowly).

You should also note that the [technique you're using](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html) to permute the array is **biased**; not every permutation is equally likely.  You might want to use a shuffling algorithm that is known to be unbiased, such as the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Alternatively, you can use a really simple technique to shuffle. It's slightly inefficient, but unbiased:

```
var rand = new Random();
return buttons.OrderBy(button => rand.Next()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Dang, I feel dumb. I need to not drink while coding ever again... Thanks!

Comment: Here's a good whitepaper that explains the consequences of biased shuffling and poor PRNG initialization: How We Learned to Cheat at Online Poker. http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/developer_gambling.php

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating the Random() object in each iteration of your loop. As the Random object uses a seed during initialization you'll find that most values will be identical and not random.

You can fix the problem by declaring the Random class as static outside the method body.

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

private Button[] scrambleBoard(Button[] buttons)
{
    for (int x = 100 * buttons.Count(); x > 0; x--)
    {
        int first = rand.Next(buttons.Count());
        int second = rand.Next(buttons.Count());


        Button temp = buttons[first];
        buttons[first] = buttons[second];
        buttons[second] = temp;
    }

    return buttons;
}
```

Comment: <The Random really doesn't need to be static, by the way> And since it is not thread-safe, if there is any chance multiple threads may use it, it *must* not be static (or you must add appropriate synchronization).

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered, but I thought I'd share a nice little trick for shuffling a collection using LINQ and Guid. This creates a randomly ordered list with a nice spread of values.

```
private Button[] scrambleBoard(Button[] buttons)
{
    return buttons.OrderBy(b => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
}
```